# Passing parameter from TFS Build Process Template to Powershell Script, with two consecutive spaces

Tags: powershell, parameters, directory, whitespace

So I have created a build process template in TFS 2012 that has to pass a path name to a Powershell Script, which in turn concatenates files in the specified directory.

Some of these path names might have two consecutive spaces, which has turned out to be a problem.

When I invoke the powershell script, I enclose the path name in single quotes, and the command that is executed looks something like this.

```
powershell C:\psScript.ps1 'C:\tmp\two  spaces\myFolder'.
```

However, when I try and open the directory in Powershell, I get the following error:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\tmp\two spaces\myFolder' 
because it does not exist.
```

The two spaces seem to have become one, and the path can't be found.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: How is 'C:\tmp\two  spaces\myFolder' being created in your script? I cannot reproduce your problem. It must be related to how you create the folders, in your script.

Comment: I actually just found the solution.
For some reason, using single quotes didn't preserve the spaces, but when I used double quotes and THEN single quotes, it worked fine.

So my call ended up like this:
    powershell C:\psScript.ps1 "'C:\tmp\two  spaces\myFolder'"

Comment: I am still curious as to how the folders are being created? Are you making use of "md" command?

Comment: @jashrand - it is OK to answer your own question (and mark it as the answer) which would be useful for folks who might have the same question but not bother to read these comments.